# Integration from sfdc with sft

Tags: salesforce, sftp

My requirement is:

I have to create a CSV file or spreadsheet which contains usernames and emails. The file will be automatically generated and stored in with help of batch script and scheduler. I want to send the file to secure a file system (sftp) without using third party software. This task should be in an automated way.

Could you please tell me feasible solution for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Secure File Transfer Protocol to insert data into Salesforce.  You must access an appropriate API.  There are several clients available, including The Apex Data Loader.  [This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) describes using the command line interface to automate uploads.  The Apex Data Loader makes connections over SSL and also requires you to provide your User's [Security Token](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glADAAY).

It is also possible to [modify Salesforce objects from Heroku](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1api/Content/heroku_quick_start.htm).

Both of these are Salesforce applications, not 3rd party.